# Alternative to SecureString on a .net Standard library?

Tags: c#, .net-standard, securestring

I have a .net framework 4.7 library with extensions methods, one of them use a securestring, but I would like to convert this library to .net Standard 1.6. However, It is not possible to use the SecureString type.

So I would like to know if there are alternatives to SecureString in .net Standard.

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.SecureString/?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`SecureString` is available for **.NET Core** via the `System.Security.SecureString` NuGet package. This NuGet package currently cannot be used in .NET Standard libraries as its implementation is specific to .NET Core. To use this package, you have to create a .NET Core library.

In .NET Standard 2.0, this type will be available without the need to add a NuGet package and you'll be able to use it in a .NET Standard library.